# Extract CC list full mail address from outlook mail

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

I can use 
`cc = message.CC` to display the list of Carbon copy names for a mail item. However they are just names. How can I display full mailadress for cc list?

for sender mail address，I can use `message.sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress` to get. but message.CC cannot use this because the output data type is “str”. message.sender output data type is `win32com.client.CDispatch`.

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `MailItem.Recipients` collection, check for the items with `Recipient.Type == olCC`. use `Recipeint.AddressEntry` property to retrieve the corresponding `AddressEntry` object. Check if `AddressEntry.Type == "EX"`. If yes, use `AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`, otherwise use `AddressEntry.Address`.

Comment: Thanks man！U perfectly help. The only difference is the recipient type for CC says“2” from my side. Thanks anyway

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you!